# TestCafe DragNDrop Not Working When DropZone Appears After DragStart

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, automated-tests, testcafe, ui-testing

I recently started to use [TestCafe](http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/) and I'm trying to utilize `t.dragToElement(selector, destinationSelector)` method.

The problem is, the dropzone does not appear until I start dragging. It is hidden using `display: none` and appears onDragStart. Therefore TestCafe fails with

`The element that matches the specified "destinationSelector" is not visible.`

**Q: Any ideas, how to make TestCafe click & hold & drag a little bit & then drag to destination & then release?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately now it is quite complicated (if possible at all). But it looks that `dragToElement` definitely should be implemented in the way allowing your use case, so I created an issue at our GitHub: [#1374](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/1374), and it will work out-of-the box. Feel free to comment it on GitHub, add some details, etc.

Comment: Cool, thanks for such quick reaction. Will be checking GitHub and hoping it will soon be implemented.